# Get the value select of a foreign key in a validation

Tags: laravel

I am stuck about the get the value of a select.
If my validation system is wrong. I would like to get the value of my dropdownlist.

```
<fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('ville') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
 <label for="company-content">Ville</label>
 <select name="fk_localite" id="fk_localite" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ old('fk_localite')}}"/>
  <option value="">Choix ville</option>
      @foreach($localites as $localite)
  <option value="{{$localite->id}}" {{ old('ville') == $localite->id ? {{ 'selected' }}>{{$localite->ville}}</option>
       @endforeach
     {!! $errors->first('fk_localite', '<span class="helpblock">:message</span>') !!}
</select>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fix this **bug** : 
From

```
<option value="{{$localite->id}}" {{ old('ville') == $localite->id ? {{ 'selected' }}>{{$localite->ville}}</option>
```

To

```
<option value="{{$localite->id}}" {{ old('ville') == $localite->id ?  'selected' : '' }} >
{{$localite->ville}}
</option>
```

Then getting selected value in controller :

```
$selected = $request->input('fk_localite');
//For example if selected item value was 123 now $selected is 123 .
```

Comment: Ohhh thank you a lot my problem is solve... Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Your Welcome , Glad to help :)